# Provide args to Azure Container Instance entrypoint

Tags: azure, docker

With Docker, you can define CMD and ENTRYPOINT together such that the former becomes the arguments to the latter:

```
ENTRYPOINT [CMD]
```

This way, the end-user doesn't have to know or care about the entrypoint.

How can this be accomplished with Azure Container Instance? The documentation [suggests that it can't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-start-command), providing only `--command-line` which seems to replace both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to overwrite `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` at run time is by using the `--entrypoint` flag when running a docker container. Do note that you can't overwrite the `CMD` without overwriting the `ENTRYPOINT` as well (unless the entrypoint is empty), and obviously the opposite is true too.

The article that you linked explains how `--command-line` can be used to overwrite `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` at run time, similarly to how you would do that with a `docker run` command.